# Create a Magento shopping voucher code, first 3 products to be free and thereafter 10% off on rest

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

I'm having a giveaway soon, so will be making several codes

But I can't figure out how to make a voucher to have first 3 products free and thereafter at %10 percent off + p&p its going to be valid for a specific category

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AM3bFO0.png check this , what i have done is made a rule for 10 percent off free with out code and for first 3 you need to have the special code , but i cant get the first 3 free to work it makes all the products in that coupon selection free !

Answer (score 1):

In Magento coupon codes are unique. But you can remove this limitation and create 2 special promotions rules with the same coupon codes.

One gives 10% off all products, another makes the first 3 item free.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but i cant make the first 3 free as its just making every product in that list free . any suggestions ? [link]http://i.imgur.com/AM3bFO0.png

Comment: Have you tried to disable all extensions?